# How do I reproduce this layout and typography?

Tags: fonts, typography

IMHO, some math books published by the German company [Hanser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Hanser_Verlag) have a very pleasing layout. I'm attaching an example below (screenshot from Google Books which I hope is fair use).

I guess this was done with LaTeX, but I'm not very good at figuring out fonts from just staring at them. Which settings would I have to use to reproduce a similar layout, including the fonts used for math?

[image]

Comment: For the layout of chapters, sections, &c., you should take a look at the documentation of `titlesec`. Clearly, you should use the `fleqn` option, and for shaded equations, it can easily be done with `empheq`. Also, the baseline skip seems to be a little more than usually with LaTeX. You may add something like `\linespread{1.08}`.

Comment: For the 2nd MWE you can put `\ssfamily` to change the fonts of the section, ecc. Always for my opinion the font for the section, paragraph, ecc...is similar to Arial but in this case is necessary to use XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seeing your template, in my humble opinion, it seems to use the `fourier` package.

[image]

Here you can find several fonts with LaTeX math support: https://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My version}
\blindtext[1]
\[\pi D_n(\varphi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos (k\varphi)\]
\end{document}
```

### Addendum

This is only a bad copy for your template :-) You can change the style of the chapter with Sonny, Lenny, etc.: *[Fncychap: titoli fantasiosi di capitoli in classe book LaTeX](http://zuccala.blogspot.com/2009/02/fncychap-titoli-di-capitoli-in-classe.html)*

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries\color{gray}{\large}}{\color{gray}{$\blacksquare\quad$}\thesection}{1em}{}
  \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\Large\bfseries\color{gray}{\large}}{\color{gray}{$\blacksquare\quad$}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My version}
\section{Dirichlet Kernfunktionen}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Name 1}
\blindmathpaper
\subsubsection{Name 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was unsure as to whether it might be `Bookman` (via the free clone TeX Gyre Bonum), but you've convinced me  (+1). It may be completed for text by `erewhon` which adds true small caps, and some other features.

Comment: @Bernard :-).-) I used Bookman old style in my graduation thesis. The glyphs I saw closest to me from the catalogue look like fourier glyphs. Then I can do mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is pretty much exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Frunobulax I am very glad to help you and other users. For my little experience it is necessary to create the same style very lot of time. My best regards and you return here sometimes :-). Bye.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but I came across this book again today and wasn't entirely convinced by the choice of font.  I played around a little more and I'm now pretty sure the font is Utopia.  Here are some lines from my initial example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[totalwidth=138.5mm]{geometry} % just to match the example
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\linespread{1.15}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
In Abschnitt 4.11 lernten wir zum ersten Mal die Fourierreihen kennen.  Wir
erz\"ahlten in diesem Zusammenhang, dass Dirichlet die Summenformel
\[ 1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos k\varphi = 2\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty
  \delta(\phi-2\pi n) \] erahnte.  Tats\"achlich konnte er sie so nicht
anschreiben, denn Dirichlet lebte hundert Jahre, bevor die verallgemeinerten
Funktionen, insbesondere die diracsche Deltafunktion, entdeckt wurden.
Tats\"achlich berechnete Dirichlet nicht die links angeschriebene unendliche
Reihe, sondern deren Partialsummen
\[ D_n(\varphi) = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k\varphi \]
\end{document}
```

If printed with a good laser printer this really is a perfect match with the book.  The only difference that I can spot is with the greek characters in math formulas.  I tried all `greekfamily` options of the `mathdesign` package, but none of them seems to fit.

[image: compare with example shown in question above]

**EDIT**: What I wrote above was pretty much nonsense based on wrong settings.  Sebastiano was spot on with `fourier`.  For the sake of completeness, here's the corrected version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[totalwidth=136mm]{geometry} % just to match the example
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\linespread{1.15}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
In Abschnitt 4.11 lernten wir zum ersten Mal die Fourierreihen kennen.  Wir
erz\"ahlten in diesem Zusammenhang, dass Dirichlet die Summenformel
\[ 1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos k\varphi = 2\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty
  \delta(\varphi-2\pi n) \] erahnte.  Tats\"achlich konnte er sie so nicht
anschreiben, denn Dirichlet lebte hundert Jahre, bevor die verallgemeinerten
Funktionen, insbesondere die diracsche Deltafunktion, entdeckt wurden.
Tats\"achlich berechnete Dirichlet nicht die links angeschriebene unendliche
Reihe, sondern deren Partialsummen
\[ D_n(\varphi) = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k\varphi \]
\end{document}
```

[image: The fourier version]